Tips on using fibafuse for drywall repair
I had a long gash in the drywall from one of my kids dragging something across it. I filled the gash with joint compound.

Doesn't look too bad. But I also have some Fibafuse and I hear good things about using that. So I add a layer of Fibafuse on top.

Can't see the gash as well now but can clearly see the outline of the tape. I could really lay the mud on thick so as to hide the tape but then it seems like that's going to cause me a lot more work down the line with sanding. And if I try to really thin out the mud over the Fibafuse than it seems like it starts to fray.
Am I doing this right? Will it look better tomorrow? Looking from the side, the repair looks flat, so maybe once it dries and I add a second coat over a wider area it will all blend well?

Fibafuse is just like any other tape, and there’s plenty of information in here about taping and skimming.

The mud should be feathered out to at least 12 to 18 inches from that patch to blend it into the wall.  If the feathering is done right, there should be only a tiny bit of sanding and you will need to look very carefully for a lump/bump on the wall.

You did not need the tape of any kind on that repair.  It was a small "gash" that was not in need of reinforcement that the tape provides. It could have been filled with compound only and lightly sanded .
Now you have a much larger repair. As crip659 stated in comments, now you need to feather with compound out 12 to 18 inches and sand lightly when dry. Prime and paint.

Thanks. I sort of had the inkling as I was doing it that I was being overzealous with the tape. The gash was actually pretty deep which is why I thought to add some more reinforcement. But appreciate the comment. I'll just feather it out and it'll look fine.

Now your problem will be matching the texture of the feathered out j/c to match the rest of the wall.

Texture with fine orange peel from a can. Use circular motions. Before texture, use a very slightly damp sponge to feather the edges of your drywall compound.
